# jQuery.ajax: How do I limit the data processed from the remote server?

Tags: jquery

In the code below, when the input string is "tobacco" (without quotes), the alert function fires in an endless loop of terms. The "terms" are derived from the result set (which is set to 50 to ensure a rich set of data to seed the keywords). However, for some terms, the amount of keywords returned is way too high.

What can I do in the script below to set a max for the number of keywords to process and then proceed once that max has been reached?

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/"
        +jQuery('#my_keyword').val()+"?"
        +"appid=myID"
        +"&lang=en"
        +"&format=json"
        +"&count=50"
        +"&view=keyterms"
        +"&callback=?", 
        success: function(data)
            {
                var keywords = new Array();
                jQuery.each(data['ysearchresponse']['resultset_web'],
                        function(i,item) 
                            {
                            jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'], 
                            function(i,kw)
                                {
                                key = kw.toLowerCase();
                                alert(key);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but if you just want to limit the number of keywords you iterate through, why not set up a limit counter?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/"
    +jQuery('#my_keyword').val()+"?"
    +"appid=myID"
    +"&lang=en"
    +"&format=json"
    +"&count=50"
    +"&view=keyterms"
    +"&callback=?", 
    success: function(data)
        {
            var keywords = new Array();
            var keywordsNumber = 0;
            var keywordsMax = 20;
            jQuery.each(data['ysearchresponse']['resultset_web'],
                    function(i,item) 
                        {
                        if (keywordNumber == keywordsMax) { return false; } // Same as 'continue' in a regular loop
                        jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'], 
                        function(i,kw)
                            {
                            key = kw.toLowerCase();
                            keywordsNumber++;
                            alert(key);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I'm asking the right question :) Problem is that on some queries, My loader never disappears and the script never seems to finish and the alert(key) seems to be an endless loop of terms. I'm trying to limit the number of terms returned to avoid the endless loop.

Comment: Hmm... You could slice() the item['keyterms']['terms'] array (say, terms = item['keyterms']['terms'].slice(0,keywordsMax)), and run jQuery.each on that array? Bit of a hack still unfortunately, but I'm not sure there's any way of limiting the number of results that are returned, only the amount you iterate through.